# I am getting error on ontap how can i solve it is it because of null safety how can i solve it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

String imagepath, String buttonName, double size, Function onTap) {
return InkWell(
onTap: onTap,

Comment: Can you share your ontap code

Comment: Please share the log

Comment: Widget buttonItem(
      String imagepath, String buttonName, double size,  Function onTap) {
    return InkWell(
     onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
        height: 60,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.black,
          elevation: 8,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            side: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),

Comment: @Gouravs please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: thanks for the information am newbie here

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `onTap: onTap,` with `onTap: () => onTap(),`
and call like this

```
 buttonItem("assets/me.jpg", "click", 120.0, () {
            print("tapped");
          }),
```